# Child page excerpt

Tags: child-pages

I have a parent page with some child pages inside.
What I'm looking to do is display every child page excerpt and some other information inside its own cell on the parent page.
Does anyone know how this can be achieved ?

```
<div class="parent page">

    <?php  $args = array(
          'parent' => $post->ID,
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post_status' => 'publish'
      ); 
      $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
      <div class="childcells"> 
      <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
       <div class="childcell">
          <div class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></div>
          <div class="myclasstitle"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></div>
          <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'desc', true); ?></span>
      <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
            Read more
          </a>

      </div>
```

?>

Comment: what is the result of your code? what is different from what you expect?

Comment: result is every other info except child page excerpt. i added `  <?php echo get_the_excerpt ($page); ?>`  but i get an error

Comment: try `get_the_excerpt( $page->ID )` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Comment: I tried that too, but same error appears

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_excerpt()` won't work in your code if you add content to the main WYSIWYG editor instead of the excerpt field.

Check how [get_the_excerpt()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.5/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L374) work and try to find out filter hook with `get_the_excerpt` hook name.

Please try the following code, hope you'll get the expected result.

```
<div class="parent page">
    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'parent'      => $post->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $children = get_pages( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $children ) ) :
        ?>
        <div class="childcells"> 
            <?php
            foreach ( $children as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                ?>
                <div class="childcell">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small-thumb' ); ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="myclasstitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'desc', true ); ?></span>
                    <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i have two question; 1-  how i can control the length of excerpt? & 2- why the order of child pages is based on alphabet or numbering? how i can fix this?